# Shadowing TimeZone.getDefault using Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm having some troubles shadowing `TimeZone.getDefault()` using Robolectric since my AppTest.class is not using my static shadow mwthod in ShadowTimeZone.class.

**AppTest.class**

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "../App/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class AppTest{

    @Test
    @Config(shadows = {ShadowTimeZone.class})
    public void testTimeZone() {    
        String expectedTimeZoneId = "Europe/London";

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

        assertThat(timeZone.getID(), equalTo(expectedTimeZoneId));
    }
}
```

**ShadowTimeZone.class**

```
@Implements(TimeZone.class)
public class ShadowTimeZone {

    @Implementation
    public static TimeZone getDefault() {
        return TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use a shadow at all. Use `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"))` before your test or in a `@Before` setup method.

If you still want to use a shadow, the actual signature for getDefault is `public static synchronized`, so you may need to add `synchronized` to your shadow method to match.

Answer (score 0):

By default you can only shadow classes from android package. But you can add more classes to work with shadows. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29641926/3619179