# Robolectric shadow not working

Tags: java, android, shadow, robolectric

I'm trying to create a test with **Robolectric**. My goal is to be able to replace the functionality of one class (that comes for example from a library and I can't modify the code) from a custom behaviour.

I created this small test to simulate what I want to do:

```java
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(shadows = {ShadowMessenger.class})
public class TestShadow {

    @Test
    public void testMessenger() {
        OriginalMessenger messenger = new OriginalMessenger();
        String message = messenger.getMessage();
        Assert.assertEquals("Shadow messenger", message);
    }

    public static class OriginalMessenger {

        public String getMessage() {
            return "Original messenger";
        }
    }

    @Implements(OriginalMessenger.class)
    public static class ShadowMessenger extends OriginalMessenger {

        @Implementation
        public String getMessage() {
            return "Shadow messenger";
        }
    }
}
```

In the example, *OriginalMessenger* is the class that is in the library and provides a default functionality. And *ShadowMessenger* is the class that contains the custom behaviour that I want to apply whenever I use *OriginalMessenger*.

However when I run the test it fails. The content of *message* is "Original messenger". As if the *ShadowMessenger* was never used.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why make a shadow? Why not `mock` or `stub` it out?

Comment: How do I achieve the same result using mocks and stubs?

Comment: Oh I see nenick solved your problem? You can use EasyMock/PowerMock to mock out of your class or Spock(Robospock). Check out an example here: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/BurrowsAppsExamples/blob/master/Lib-BurrowsApps/src/test/java/burrows/apps/example/lib/utils/PlayServicesUtilsTest.java.

Comment: If I apply nenick's answer I get an StackOverflowError, I don't know why. I can't make it run with PowerMock. I get: `Extension API internal error: org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl could not be located in classpath`. I took the dependencies from the example. Thanks for the help.

Comment: are you using "testCompile"? Did you setup the annotations?

Comment: Yes. I have these:

testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:1.6.2'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.2'
testCompile 'org.easymock:easymock:3.3.1'

Here is the code:
https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/android-studio-template/tree/master/app/src/test/java/com/example

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. If your class is a simple pojo, extending it and overriding the one method would be fine for a `stub` or `dummy` class for testing. If your class requires internet or a database, it would be a good idea to `mock` or `spy` it and make it "return" output you were expecting.

Comment: I don't know if I can apply that in my case. I have a class `A` that I want to test. `A` needs the class `B` to work. But `B` is in a library so I can't modify it or extend it. I want to test `A` but without using the original `B`. I want to use a fake `B` without changing the code of `A`. That's why I thought I could use shadows. My idea was to say: whenever the code requires `B`, let's use fake `B` instead. One possible solution could be using dependency injection, where I inject `B` (or fake `B`) into `A` to be used. But I wanted to know if it's possible with shadows.

Comment: Is `OriginalMessenger` open source? Based on your example, it really only looks like you are wanting `getMessage()` to be overwritten.

Comment: That code just belongs to a sample project. It's not related to the actual code that I want to test (I can't publish it). I made the scenario with the OriginalMessenger/ShadowMessenger just to practice shadows to see if it was possible what I wanted to achieve. If I solve it in the messengers scenario then I will translate it to the original project.

Comment: Alright, I have made my suggestions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Original you can only shadow android classes. But with a custom robolectric test runner you can also shadow your own classes.

Robolectric 3.1.4 (RobolectricGradleTestRunner was completely removed, so you need to override method described below in RobolectricTestRunner)

```
@Override
protected ShadowMap createShadowMap() {
    return new ShadowMap.Builder()
        .addShadowClass(OriginalMessenger.class, ShadowMessenger.class, true, true, true)
        .build();
}
```

Robolectric 3.0

```
@Override
public InstrumentationConfiguration createClassLoaderConfig() {
    InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder builder = InstrumentationConfiguration.newBuilder();
    builder.addInstrumentedClass(OriginalMessenger.class.getName());
    return builder.build();
}
```

Robolectric 2.4

```
@Override
protected ClassLoader createRobolectricClassLoader(Setup setup, SdkConfig sdkConfig) {
    return super.createRobolectricClassLoader(new ExtraShadows(setup), sdkConfig);
}

class ExtraShadows extends Setup {
    private Setup setup;

    public ExtraShadows(Setup setup) {
        this.setup = setup;
    }

    public boolean shouldInstrument(ClassInfo classInfo) {
        boolean shoudInstrument = setup.shouldInstrument(classInfo);
        return shoudInstrument
                || classInfo.getName().equals(OriginalMessenger.class.getName());
    }
}
```

example project https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template/

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about it

Comment: If I do that I get a StackOverflowError. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: Not without seeing the stacktrace. Which method is called circular?

Comment: Here is the stack trace:
http://pastebin.com/5pVB7zrY

Here are the classes I'm working with:
https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/android-studio-template/tree/master/app/src/test/java/com/example

Comment: `public static class ShadowMessenger extends OriginalMessenger {` shadows don't need a base class

Comment: when you like to access the original object then use @RealObject http://robolectric.org/extending/

Comment: I removed the extends and now it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @nenick, How about robolectric 3.0. I can find bytecode.Setup class in this version.

Comment: Yes it was replaced. A possible new position to add own shadows could be `protected ShadowMap createShadowMap() {...}`

Comment: @Phien: I managed to do it in Robolectric 3.0 by overriding the `createClassLoaderConfig()` method on the test runner and building a `InstrumentationConfiguration` instance with my instrumented packages and classes added.